# How do I wrap a string in a file in Python?

Tags: python, string, file, stringio

How do I create a file-like object (same duck type as File) with the contents of a string?

Answer (score 163, accepted):

For Python 2.x, use the [StringIO](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) module.  For example:

```
>>> from cStringIO import StringIO
>>> f = StringIO('foo')
>>> f.read()
'foo'
```

I use cStringIO (which is faster), but note that it doesn't [accept Unicode strings that cannot be encoded as plain ASCII strings](http://docs.python.org/lib/module-cStringIO.html).  (You can switch to StringIO by changing  "from cStringIO" to "from StringIO".)

For Python 3.x, use the [`io`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#text-i-o) module.

```
f = io.StringIO('foo')
```

Comment: There is a reason now to use cStringIO: cStringIO doesn't support unicode strings.

Comment: I think a better idea is to do 'import cStringIO as StringIO'.  That way if you need to switch to the pure python implementation for any reason, you only need to change one line..

Comment: This works for Python2.7, too: `io.StringIO(u'foo')` I would use this

Answer (score 49):

In Python 3.0:

```
import io

with io.StringIO() as f:
    f.write('abcdef')
    print('gh', file=f)
    f.seek(0)
    print(f.read())
```

The output is:

```
'abcdefgh'
```

Answer (score 14):

If your file-like object is expected to contain bytes, the string should first be encoded as bytes, and then a [BytesIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#text-i-o) object can be used instead. In Python 3:

```
from io import BytesIO

string_repr_of_file = 'header\n byline\n body\n body\n end'
function_that_expects_bytes(BytesIO(bytes(string_repr_of_file,encoding='utf-8')))
```

Answer (score 11):

This works for Python2.7 and Python3.x:

```
io.StringIO(u'foo')
```