# Python file interface for strings

Tags: python, string, file

Is there a Python class that wraps the `file` interface (read, write etc.) around a string? I mean something like the `stringstream` classes in C++.

I was thinking of using it to redirect the output of `print` into a string, like this

```
sys.stdout = string_wrapper()
print "foo", "bar", "baz"
s = sys.stdout.to_string() #now s == "foo bar baz"
```

EDIT: This is a duplicate of [How do I wrap a string in a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141449/how-do-i-wrap-a-string-in-a-file-in-python)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, there is StringIO:

```
import StringIO
import sys


sys.stdout = StringIO.StringIO()
print "foo", "bar", "baz"
s = sys.stdout.getvalue()
```

Answer (score 2):

For better performance, note that you can also use cStringIO.  But also note that this isn't very portable to python 3.