# a StringIO like class, that extends django.core.files.File

Tags: python, django

```
class MyModel(models.Model)
 image = models.FileField(upload_to="blagh blagh...")
 #more spam...
```

I have a file in memory and I want to save it via Django FileField save method, like this:

```
photo.image.save(name, buffer) # second arg should be django File
```

I've tried to use StringIO, but it doesn't extend django.core.files.File and thus doesn't implement method chunks(). I've wrapped it in a File object like that:

```
buffile = File(buffer, name) # first argument should be a file
photo.image.save(name, buffile)
```

But File methods use size and name fields of supplied file. StringIO doesn't define them.
I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141449/how-do-i-wrap-a-string-in-a-file-in-python/143532#143532), but the link is dead

Comment: Use the [Image](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/introduction.htm) class.

Comment: I considered that, but then I would not use django mechanism for naming files (if a file with a given name exists, add underscore to the filename). And yes, I know, I could do that by myself and I could do that in other way, but It would be the best if I did that, like I described before.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you've got a stream of bytes, which you'd like to save to a FileField/ImageField, here's some code that might help:

```
>>> from django.core.files.uploadedfile import InMemoryUploadedFile
>>> from cStringIO import StringIO
>>> buf = StringIO(data)  # `data` is your stream of bytes
>>> buf.seek(0, 2)  # Seek to the end of the stream, so we can get its length with `buf.tell()`
>>> file = InMemoryUploadedFile(buf, "image", "some_filename.png", None, buf.tell(), None)
>>> photo.image.save(file.name, file)  # `photo` is an instance of `MyModel`
>>> photo.image
<ImageFieldFile: ...>
```

Some notes:

- You can make up whatever name you want for the image, but you'll probably want to keep the extension accurate
- The second argument to `InMemoryUploadedFile` is the name of the field in your model, hence "image"

It's a little finnicky, but it gets the job done. Hopefully, the API will get cleaned up a bit more in 1.3/4.

**Edit:**
See [Jason's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330677/a-stringio-like-class-that-extends-django-core-files-file/3332232#3332232) for a much simpler way of doing this, though you'll still want to know the filename of the image.

Answer (score 34):

You can use ContentFile instead of File

```
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

photo.image.save(name, ContentFile(buffer))
```

Comment: Neat! This is so much simpler than my solution...+1

Comment: If the buffer is a `StringIO` object you will need to do `ContentFile(buffer.getvalue())`

Answer (score 8):

Re Jason's answer. Note that ContentFile only accepts strings, not any file-like object. Here's one that does --

```
from django.core.files.base import *

class StreamFile(ContentFile):
    """
    Django doesn't provide a File wrapper suitable 
    for file-like objects (eg StringIO)
    """
    def __init__(self, stream):
        super(ContentFile, self).__init__(stream)
        stream.seek(0, 2)
        self.size = stream.tell()
```

Now you can do stuff like this --

```
photo.image.save(name, StreamFile(io))
```