# Saving a decoded temporary image to Django Imagefield

Tags: django, django-1.3

I'm trying to save images which have been passed to me as Base64 encoded text into a Django Imagefield.

But it seems to not be saving correctly. The database reports all my images are stored as "" when it should report them as a filename for example:

```
"template_images/template_folders/myImage.png"
```

The code that's trying to save my images is as follows:

```
elif model_field.get_internal_type() == "ImageField" or model_field.get_internal_type() == "FileField":  # Convert files from base64 back to a file.
    if field_elt.text is not None:
        setattr(instance, model_field.name, File(b64decode(field_elt.text)))
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

After reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330677/a-stringio-like-class-that-extends-django-core-files-file/3332232#3332232), I got this to work:

```
from base64 import b64decode
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

image_data = b64decode(b64_text)
my_model_instance.cool_image_field = ContentFile(image_data, 'whatup.png')
my_model_instance.save()
```

Therefore, I suggest you change your code to:

```
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

# Your other code...

elif model_field.get_internal_type() == "ImageField" or model_field.get_internal_type() == "FileField":  # Convert files from base64 back to a file.
    if field_elt.text is not None:
        image_data = b64decode(field_elt.text)
        setattr(instance, model_field.name, ContentFile(image_data, 'myImage.png'))
```

Then, assuming your `ImageField` is defined with the `upload_to` argument set to `template_images/template_folders/`, you should see the file save down to `YOUR_MEDIA_URL/template_images/template_folders/myImage.png`

Comment: I tried to follow the same approach, though I get 'Incorrect padding' on decode. Any suggestion?

Comment: Yup, you don't want to include the initial  data:image/gif;base64,  bit but then I guess you probably know that by now, just for the people that came here via Google like I did.

Comment: i think this one might fail because you dont need to include `data:image/*;base64,` part of the file.

Answer (score 2):

Another good approach based on this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28036805/6143656 tried it and tested in django 1.10

I made a function for decoded base64 file.

```
def decode_base64_file(data):

    def get_file_extension(file_name, decoded_file):
        import imghdr

        extension = imghdr.what(file_name, decoded_file)
        extension = "jpg" if extension == "jpeg" else extension

        return extension

    from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
    import base64
    import six
    import uuid

    # Check if this is a base64 string
    if isinstance(data, six.string_types):
        # Check if the base64 string is in the "data:" format
        if 'data:' in data and ';base64,' in data:
            # Break out the header from the base64 content
            header, data = data.split(';base64,')

        # Try to decode the file. Return validation error if it fails.
        try:
            decoded_file = base64.b64decode(data)
        except TypeError:
            TypeError('invalid_image')

        # Generate file name:
        file_name = str(uuid.uuid4())[:12] # 12 characters are more than enough.
        # Get the file name extension:
        file_extension = get_file_extension(file_name, decoded_file)

        complete_file_name = "%s.%s" % (file_name, file_extension, )

        return ContentFile(decoded_file, name=complete_file_name)
```

Then you can call the function

```
import decode_base64_file

p = Post(content='My Picture', image=decode_based64_file(your_base64_file))
p.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is the cleanest and shortest way to do this.

Here is how you can handle a Base64 encoded image file in a post request at the Django-based (drf also) API end which saves it as an ImageField.

Let say you have a Model as follows:

```
Class MyImageModel(models.Model):
      image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'geo_entity_pic')
      data=model.CharField()
```

So the Corresponding Serializer would be as follows:

```
 from drf_extra_fields.fields import Base64ImageField

 Class MyImageModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializers):
      image=Base64ImageField()
      class meta:
         model=MyImageModel
         fields= ('data','image')
      def create(self, validated_data):
        image=validated_data.pop('image')
        data=validated_data.pop('data')
       return MyImageModel.objects.create(data=data,image=image)
```

The corresponding View can be as follows:

```
elif request.method == 'POST':
    serializer = MyImageModelSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=201)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

Notice In the Serializer  I have used Implementation of Base64ImageField provided in the module [django-extra-field](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-extra-fields%20%22Django-Extra-Fields)

To install this module run the command

```
pip install pip install django-extra-fields
```

Import the same and Done!

Send (via post method) your image as an Base64 encoded String in JSON object along with any other data you have.