# Save canvas element to file

Tags: javascript, html

**How to post a canvas element as type file?**

I have an image in a canvas element

```
<canvas id="canvas"  width="640" height="480"></canvas>
```

How to post it back to the server as a `<input type=file>`

Suggested solution:

> < input type=file > does not provide any kind of write access - it is
>   read-only:  However you can use ´FormData´ to emulate blob-populated
>   form submissions in JavaScript code

From [upload and save screenshot taken from users webcam in django --canvas element to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25159928/upload-and-save-screenshot-taken-from-users-webcam-in-django-canvas-element-to)

How to take the input elements from the `<form>` and post them, replacing
 the  form element with the data in the canvas element?

**Background:**
I captured the image with code from https://davidwalsh.name/browser-camera

because `<input type="file" accept="image/*" id="capture" capture="camera">` 
does not work on some browsers. But the code posted by david walsh looks to work on more browsers.

Code by david walsh:

```
 <!--
    Ideally these elements aren't created until it's confirmed that the 
    client supports video/camera, but for the sake of illustrating the 
    elements involved, they are created with markup (not JavaScript)
-->
<video id="video" width="640" height="480" autoplay></video>
<button id="snap">Snap Photo</button>
<canvas id="canvas"  width="640" height="480"></canvas>
<script>
// Grab elements, create settings, etc.
var video = document.getElementById('video');

// Get access to the camera!
if(navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
    // Not adding `{ audio: true }` since we only want video now
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }).then(function(stream) {
        video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        video.play();
    });
}

/* Legacy code below: getUserMedia  */

else if(navigator.getUserMedia) { // Standard
    navigator.getUserMedia({ video: true }, function(stream) {
        video.src = stream;
        video.play();
    }, errBack);
} else if(navigator.webkitGetUserMedia) { // WebKit-prefixed
    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({ video: true }, function(stream){
        video.src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
        video.play();
    }, errBack);
} else if(navigator.mozGetUserMedia) { // Mozilla-prefixed
    navigator.mozGetUserMedia({ video: true }, function(stream){
        video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        video.play();
    }, errBack);
}

// Elements for taking the snapshot
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var video = document.getElementById('video');

// Trigger photo take
document.getElementById("snap").addEventListener("click", function() {
    context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480);
});

</script>
```

Comment: Did you try : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673122/how-to-save-canvas-as-an-image-with-canvas-todataurl  or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112321/how-to-save-canvas-as-png-image

Comment: Agree, looks like a duplicate question. I need to improve my searching skills. Thanks