# Django REST Framework upload image: "The submitted data was not a file"

Tags: python, angularjs, django, django-rest-framework

I am leaning how to upload file in Django, and here I encounter a should-be-trivial problem, with the error:

> The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form.

Below is the detail.

---

**Note:** I also looked at [Django Rest Framework ImageField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20303252/django-rest-framework-imagefield), and I tried

```
serializer = ImageSerializer(data=request.data, files=request.FILES)
```

but I get

> TypeError: `__init__()` got an unexpected keyword argument 'files'

---

I have a `Image` model which I would like to interact with via Django REST framework:

## models.py

```
class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='item_images')
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        User, related_name='uploaded_item_images',
        blank=False,
    )
    time_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

## serializers.py

```
class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image = serializers.ImageField(
        max_length=None, use_url=True,
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ("id", 'image', 'owner', 'time_created', )
```

## settings.py

```
'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
    'rest_framework.parsers.FormParser',
    'rest_framework.parsers.MultiPartParser',
),
```

The front end (using AngularJS and `angular-restmod` or `$resource`) send `JSON` data with `owner` and `image` of the form:

## Input:

```
{"owner": 5, "image": "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4QqdRXhpZgAATU0A..."}
```

In the backend, `request.data` shows

```
{u'owner': 5, u'image': u'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4QqdRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAA..."}
```

But then `ImageSerializer(data=request.data).errors` shows the error

```
ReturnDict([('image', [u'The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form.'])])
```

I wonder what I should do to fix the error?

---

**EDIT: JS part**

The related **front end** codes consists of two parts: a `angular-file-dnd` `directive` (available [here](https://github.com/onemightyroar/angular-file-dnd)) to drop the file onto the page and `angular-restmod`, which provides CRUD operations:

```
<!-- The template: according to angular-file-dnd, -->
<!-- it will store the dropped image into variable $scope.image -->
<div file-dropzone="[image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif]" file="image" class='method' data-max-file-size="3" file-name="imageFileName">
  <div layout='row' layout-align='center'>
    <i class="fa fa-upload" style='font-size:50px;'></i>
  </div>
  <div class='text-large'>Drap & drop your photo here</div>
</div>



# A simple `Image` `model` to perform `POST`
$scope.image_resource = Image.$build();

$scope.upload = function() {
  console.log("uploading");
  $scope.image_resource.image = $scope.image;
  $scope.image_resource.owner = Auth.get_profile().user_id;
  return $scope.image_resource.$save();
};
```

---

---

An update concerning the problem: right now I switched to using `ng-file-upload`, which sends image data in proper format.

Comment: Can you update your code to include the form you're using to POST the data and any relevant js?

Comment: @JamieCounsell: I have added the codes above. I did not use a `<form>` tag though.

Comment: @Lelouch : `"image": "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4QqdRXhpZgAATU0A..."` which file format is this??

Comment: @Lelouch can you share me the final solution for this

Answer (score 93, accepted):

The problem that you are hitting is that Django REST framework [expects files to be uploaded as multipart form data](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#file-upload-fields), through the standard file upload methods. This is [typically a `file` field](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications#Using_hidden_file_input_elements_using_the_click()_method), but the [JavaScript `Blob` object also works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications#Example.3A_Uploading_a_user-selected_file) for AJAX.

You are looking to upload the files using a base64 encoded string, instead of the raw file, which [is not supported by default](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/pull/1268#issuecomment-29808402). There are implementations of a [`Base64ImageField` out there](https://gist.github.com/yprez/7704036), but the most promising one [came by a pull request](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/pull/1268).

Since these were mostly designed for Django REST framework 2.x, I've improved upon the one from the pull request and created one that should be compatible with DRF 3.

## serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers    

class Base64ImageField(serializers.ImageField):
    """
    A Django REST framework field for handling image-uploads through raw post data.
    It uses base64 for encoding and decoding the contents of the file.

    Heavily based on
    https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/pull/1268

    Updated for Django REST framework 3.
    """

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
        import base64
        import six
        import uuid

        # Check if this is a base64 string
        if isinstance(data, six.string_types):
            # Check if the base64 string is in the "data:" format
            if 'data:' in data and ';base64,' in data:
                # Break out the header from the base64 content
                header, data = data.split(';base64,')

            # Try to decode the file. Return validation error if it fails.
            try:
                decoded_file = base64.b64decode(data)
            except TypeError:
                self.fail('invalid_image')

            # Generate file name:
            file_name = str(uuid.uuid4())[:12] # 12 characters are more than enough.
            # Get the file name extension:
            file_extension = self.get_file_extension(file_name, decoded_file)

            complete_file_name = "%s.%s" % (file_name, file_extension, )

            data = ContentFile(decoded_file, name=complete_file_name)

        return super(Base64ImageField, self).to_internal_value(data)

    def get_file_extension(self, file_name, decoded_file):
        import imghdr

        extension = imghdr.what(file_name, decoded_file)
        extension = "jpg" if extension == "jpeg" else extension

        return extension
```

This should be used in replacement of the standard `ImageField` provided by Django REST framework. So your serializer would become

```
class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image = Base64ImageField(
        max_length=None, use_url=True,
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ("id", 'image', 'owner', 'time_created', )
```

This should allow you to either specify a base64-encoded string, or the standard `Blob` object that Django REST framework typically expects.

Comment: Thank you! For the moment, I tried a few images, but getting `'Upload a valid image. The file you uploaded was either not an image or a corrupted image.`. Maybe it's the problem in the front end, I'll try other frontend handling. But I wonder if there is a place to test online whether a base64-enconded string is valid?

Comment: Fantastic, it now works! Uploaded files are now sitting in the desired directory. Thank you!

Comment: Another version of this appears to be on PyPI now: https://github.com/Hipo/drf-extra-fields

Comment: Works great on post requests, but on put requests, only "Raw content" is saved

Comment: I try add your solution of work with base64 encoded field and I get this output: Exception Value: 
Incorrect padding
Exception Location: /home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/fuupbol2/lib/python3.5/base64.py in b64decode, line 88  // Hee more details, just in case https://cldup.com/8EoH_qyquM.png

Comment: How should `to_representation` look like in this case?

Comment: This solution seems to ignore argument `required=False` while declaring field `image = Base64ImageField(required=False, max_length=None, use_url=True, allow_empty_file=True, allow_null=True, )` because validation fails saying the field is required

Comment: @Kevin Brown Thanks a million ton brother !! I spent whole night to resolve it and finally I resolved it. :) :D

Comment: This one can be applied not only in serializer but for directly assign the method to the imagefield when creating an object. but you have to alter this to a simple function to work. nice work!

Comment: @juankysmith were you able to solve your problem? I am facing the exact same issue. It fails even when I `allow_null=True` in the serializer.

Comment: Hi Why am i getting error that no module named `PIL` while upload file like this `image "blob:http://localhost:3000/ced70330-2afb-d848-a9d5-9091907d33ed"` from react frontedn @SadanA. @CrazyGeek @KevinBrown

Comment: Hello @Kevin, can you please check my issue?? I have the same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68002738/having-issue-in-handling-multipart-form-data-in-django-rest-framework

Comment: how can i modify the serializer to also except svg files?

Answer (score 5):

I ran in the same problem few days ago. Here is my django rest framework view to handle file uploading

## views.py

```
class PhotoUploadView(APIView):
    parser_classes = (FileUploadParser,)

    def post(self, request):
        user = self.request.user
        if not user:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
        profile  = None
        data     = None
        photo    = None

        file_form = FileUploadForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if file_form.is_valid():
            photo = request.FILES['file']
        else:
            return Response(ajax_response(file_form),status=status.HTTP_406_NOT_ACCEPTABLE)

        try:
            profile = Organizer.objects.get(user=user)
            profile.photo = photo
            profile.save()
            data    = OrganizersSerializer(profile).data
        except Organizer.DoesNotExist:
            profile = Student.objects.get(user=user)
            profile.photo = photo
            profile.save()
            data    = StudentsSerializer(profile).data

        return Response(data)
```

In front-end, I used [angular-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload) lib.

Here is my file input

```
<div ng-file-drop="" ng-file-select="" ng-model="organizer.photo" class="drop-box" drag-over-class="{accept:'dragover', reject:'dragover-err', delay:100}" ng-multiple="false" allow-dir="true" accept="image/*">
                                    Drop Images or PDFs<div>here</div>
</div>
```

And here is my upload service

## main.js

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('trulii.utils.services')
    .factory('UploadFile', UploadFile);

  UploadFile.$inject = ['$cookies', '$http','$upload','$window','Authentication'];

  /**
  * @namespace Authentication
  * @returns {Factory}
  */
  function UploadFile($cookies, $http,$upload,$window,Authentication) {
    /**
    * @name UploadFile
    * @desc The Factory to be returned
    */


    var UploadFile = {
      upload_file: upload_file,
    };
    
    return UploadFile;


    function upload_file(file) {


      return $upload.upload({
        url: '/api/users/upload/photo/', // upload.php script, node.js route, or servlet url
        //method: 'POST' or 'PUT',
        //headers: {'Authorization': 'xxx'}, // only for html5
        //withCredentials: true,
        file: file, // single file or a list of files. list is only for html5
        //fileName: 'doc.jpg' or ['1.jpg', '2.jpg', ...] // to modify the name of the file(s)
        //fileFormDataName: myFile, // file formData name ('Content-Disposition'), server side request form name
                                    // could be a list of names for multiple files (html5). Default is 'file'
        //formDataAppender: function(formData, key, val){}  // customize how data is added to the formData. 
                                                            // See #40#issuecomment-28612000 for sample code

      })

    }


  }



})();
```

Comment: The original question is using a base64-encoded image string to upload the file, instead of the browser-based file object. This probably works for the general case though, when you need to upload files asynchronously using the standard `Blob` objects.

Comment: @levi: Thank you! your solution with `angular-file-upload` is probably more flexible, which I should try out in the future. For the moment I think I'll implement @KevinBrown's solution.

Comment: When you write `file_form = FileUploadForm(request.POST,request.FILES)`, where does `FileUploadForm` come from ?

Comment: Could you give more information about the `FileUploadForm()` I get not module suggestion from that

Comment: @levi when file_form is not valid you do a Response with file_form inside ajax_response fuction, where it comes from?