# Using Django Rest Framework, how can I upload a file AND send a JSON payload?

Tags: json, django, rest, django-rest-framework, multipartform-data

I am trying to write a Django Rest Framework API handler that can receive a file as well as a JSON payload. I've set the MultiPartParser as the handler parser.

However, it seems I cannot do both. If I send the payload with the file as a multi part request, the JSON payload is available in a mangled manner in the request.data (first text part until the first colon as the key, the rest is the data). I can send the parameters in standard form parameters just fine - but the rest of my API accepts JSON payloads and I wanted to be consistent. The request.body cannot be read as it raises `*** RawPostDataException: You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream`

For example, a file and this payload in the request body:
`{"title":"Document Title", "description":"Doc Description"}`
Becomes:
`<QueryDict: {u'fileUpload': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: 20150504_115355.jpg (image/jpeg)>, <InMemoryUploadedFile: Front end lead.doc (application/msword)>], u'{%22title%22': [u'"Document Title", "description":"Doc Description"}']}>`

Is there a way to do this? Can I eat my cake, keep it and not gain any weight?

Edit: 
It was suggested that this might be a copy of  [Django REST Framework upload image: "The submitted data was not a file"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28036404). It is not. The upload and request is done in multipart, and keep in mind the file and upload of it is fine. I can even complete the request with standard form variables. But I want to see if I can get a JSON payload in there instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django REST Framework upload image: "The submitted data was not a file"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28036404/django-rest-framework-upload-image-the-submitted-data-was-not-a-file)

Comment: No, its not. edited question to explain why, though I don't even see the similarity between the two questions besides the file upload bit.

Comment: It's important to note that _`application/json` is not the same as `multipart/form-data`_, they can't be used together. And JSON doesn't support file uploading by default, you need to use a custom file field (and base64 encode it) to get file uploading support (which is where the other question comes in). You can't send JSON with multipart data, as multipart can't parse JSON at all and JSON can't parse multipart.

Comment: I suspected that Kevin but hoped somewhere there's a way to do it. I am not sure base64 won't be too limiting as far as file sizes are concerned and I don't want to put the onus on the client to encode files when sending them. I'll make the api standard multipart then.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32017119/put-request-for-image-upload-not-working-in-django-rest

Answer (score 24):

For someone who needs to upload a file and send some data, there is no straight fwd way you can get it to work. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/json-api/json-api/issues/246) in json api specs for this. One possibility i have seen is to use `multipart/related` as shown [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/multipart-upload), but i think its very hard to implement it in drf.

Finally what i had implemented was to send the request as `formdata`. You would send each file as *file* and all other data as text.
Now for sending the data as text you can have a single key called *data* and send the whole json as string in value.

Models.py

```
class Posts(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True, editable=False)
    caption = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    media = models.ImageField(blank=True, default="", upload_to="posts/")
    tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tags', related_name='posts')
```

serializers.py -> no special changes needed, not showing my serializer here as its too lengthy because of the writable ManyToMany Field implimentation.

views.py

```
class PostsViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = PostsSerializer
    parser_classes = (MultipartJsonParser, parsers.JSONParser)
    queryset = Posts.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'id'
```

You will need custom parser as shown below for parsing json.

utils.py

```
from django.http import QueryDict
import json
from rest_framework import parsers

class MultipartJsonParser(parsers.MultiPartParser):

    def parse(self, stream, media_type=None, parser_context=None):
        result = super().parse(
            stream,
            media_type=media_type,
            parser_context=parser_context
        )
        data = {}
        # find the data field and parse it
        data = json.loads(result.data["data"])
        qdict = QueryDict('', mutable=True)
        qdict.update(data)
        return parsers.DataAndFiles(qdict, result.files)
```

The request example in postman [image: case2]

EDIT:

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50514022/3701807) extended answer if you want to send each data as key value pair

Comment: This answer really helped me with multipart json + file upload. Especially I gave me an idea how to handle problems due to nested dictionary being converted into strings. I had to convert them back to proper json with my customized parser.

Comment: can you please upload the picture of postman if media and a data field is foreign key(multiple)?

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The nested serializer field ('location' in my case) is removed later on, and the API sends the response of 'tags field is required'. 
I do have the 'location' field in my parser, it just isn't passed on to validate function i think.

Comment: If you still get the 'field is required' error after trying this. You should look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68555559/django-rest-framework-drf-sets-json-field-to-empty-in-the-to-internal-value-fu/68571075#68571075

Answer (score 13):

I know this is an old thread, but I just came across this. I had to use `MultiPartParser` in order to get my file and extra data to come across together. Here's what my code looks like:

```
# views.py
class FileUploadView(views.APIView):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser,)

    def put(self, request, filename, format=None):
        file_obj = request.data['file']
        ftype    = request.data['ftype']
        caption  = request.data['caption']
        # ...
        # do some stuff with uploaded file
        # ...
        return Response(status=204)
```

My AngularJS code using `ng-file-upload` is:

```
file.upload = Upload.upload({
  url: "/api/picture/upload/" + file.name,
  data: {
    file: file,
    ftype: 'final',
    caption: 'This is an image caption'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

I send JSON and an image to create/update a product object. Below is a create APIView that works for me.

Serializer

```
class ProductCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
         model = Product
        fields = [
            "id",
            "product_name",
            "product_description",
            "product_price",
          ]
    def create(self,validated_data):
         return Product.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

View

```
from rest_framework  import generics,status
from rest_framework.parsers import FormParser,MultiPartParser

class ProductCreateAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductCreateSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAdminOrIsSelf,]
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser,FormParser,)

    def perform_create(self,serializer,format=None):
        owner = self.request.user
        if self.request.data.get('image') is not None:
            product_image = self.request.data.get('image')
            serializer.save(owner=owner,product_image=product_image)
        else:
            serializer.save(owner=owner)
```

Example test:

```
def test_product_creation_with_image(self):
    url = reverse('products_create_api')
    self.client.login(username='testaccount',password='testaccount')
    data = {
        "product_name" : "Potatoes",
        "product_description" : "Amazing Potatoes",
        "image" : open("local-filename.jpg","rb")
    }
    response = self.client.post(url,data)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code,status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Comment: Can you show your serializer too? What field do you use for the image key?

Comment: This is not sending JSON though.

Comment: can you show the image serializer too, which field is targeted

Answer (score 4):

@Nithin solution works but essentially it means you are sending JSON as strings and hence not using the actual `application/json` inside the multipart segments.

What we want is to make the backend accept data in the below format

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryrga771iuUYap8BB2
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="1x1_noexif.jpeg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryrga771iuUYap8BB2
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="myjson"; filename="blob"
Content-Type: application/json

{"hello":"world"}
------WebKitFormBoundaryrga771iuUYap8BB2
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="isDownscaled"; filename="blob"
Content-Type: application/json

false
------WebKitFormBoundaryrga771iuUYap8BB2--
```

`MultiPartParser` works with the above format but will treat those jsons as files. So we simply unmarshal those jsons by putting them to `data`.

parsers.py

```
from rest_framework import parsers

class MultiPartJSONParser(parsers.MultiPartParser):
    def parse(self, stream, *args, **kwargs):
        data = super().parse(stream, *args, **kwargs)

        # Any 'File' found having application/json as type will be moved to data
        mutable_data = data.data.copy()
        unmarshaled_blob_names = []
        json_parser = parsers.JSONParser()
        for name, blob in data.files.items():
            if blob.content_type == 'application/json' and name not in data.data:
                mutable_data[name] = json_parser.parse(blob)
                unmarshaled_blob_names.append(name)
        for name in unmarshaled_blob_names:
            del data.files[name]
        data.data = mutable_data

        return data
```

settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ..
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': [
        ..
        'myproject.parsers.MultiPartJSONParser',
    ],
}
```

This should work now.

The final bit is testing. Since the test `client` that ships with Django and REST doesn't support multipart JSON, we work around that by wrapping any JSON data.

```
import io
import json

def JsonBlob(obj):
    stringified = json.dumps(obj)
    blob = io.StringIO(stringified)
    blob.content_type = 'application/json'
    return blob

def test_simple(client, png_3x3):
    response = client.post(f'http://localhost/files/', {
            'file': png_3x3,
            'metadata': JsonBlob({'lens': 'Sigma 35mm'}),
        }, format='multipart')
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

Comment: Passing a list of data in the Json blob gets caught up in utils/html#parse_html_list. I'll post my attempt at listifying your parser in another answer since I can't do it in a comment. But first let me say thanks for your answer. Extremely helpful!

Answer (score 3):

It is very simple to use a multipart post and a regular view, if this is an option.

You send the json as a field and files as files, then process in one view.

Here is a simple python client and a Django server:

Client - sending multiple files and an arbitrary json-encoded object:

```
import json
import requests

payload = {
    "field1": 1,
    "manifest": "special cakes",
    "nested": {"arbitrary":1, "object":[1,2,3]},
    "hello": "word" }

filenames = ["file1","file2"]
request_files = {}
url="example.com/upload"

for filename in filenames:
    request_files[filename] = open(filename, 'rb')

r = requests.post(url, data={'json':json.dumps(payload)}, files=request_files)
```

Server - consuming the json and saving the files:

```
@csrf_exempt
def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = json.loads(request.POST['json']) 
        try:
            manifest = data['manifest']
            #process the json data

        except KeyError:
            HttpResponseServerError("Malformed data!")

        dir = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, "uploads")
        os.makedirs(dir, exist_ok=True)

        for file in request.FILES:
            path = os.path.join(dir,file)
            if not os.path.exists(path):
                save_uploaded_file(path, request.FILES[file])           

    else:
        return HttpResponseNotFound()

    return HttpResponse("Got json data")


def save_uploaded_file(path,f):
    with open(path, 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in f.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're getting an error along the lines of `Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received list.`, with @nithin's solution, it's because Django's `QueryDict` is getting in the way - it's specifically structured to [use a list for each entry in the dictionary](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict), and thus:

```json
{ "list": [1, 2] }
```

when parsed by `MultipartJsonParser` yields

```py
{ 'list': [[1, 2]] }
```

which trips up your serializer.

Here is an alternative which handles this case, specifically expecting the `_data` key for your JSON:

```py
from rest_framework import parsers
import json

class MultiPartJSONParser(parsers.MultiPartParser):
    def parse(self, stream, *args, **kwargs):
        data = super().parse(stream, *args, **kwargs)
        json_data_field = data.data.get('_data')
        if json_data_field is not None:
            parsed = json.loads(json_data_field)
            mutable_data = {}
            for key, value in parsed.items():
                mutable_data[key] = value
            mutable_files = {}
            for key, value in data.files.items():
                if key != '_data':
                    mutable_files[key] = value
            return parsers.DataAndFiles(mutable_data, mutable_files)

        json_data_file = data.files.get('_data')
        if json_data_file:
            parsed = parsers.JSONParser().parse(json_data_file)
            mutable_data = {}
            for key, value in parsed.items():
                mutable_data[key] = value
            mutable_files = {}
            for key, value in data.files.items():
                mutable_files[key] = value
            return parsers.DataAndFiles(mutable_data, mutable_files)

        return data
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd just like to add to @Pithikos's answer by modifying the parser to accept lists as well, in line with how DRF parses lists in serializers in `utils/html#parse_html_list`

```py
class MultiPartJSONParser(parsers.MultiPartParser):
    def parse(self, stream, *args, **kwargs):
        data = super().parse(stream, *args, **kwargs)

        # Any 'File' found having application/json as type will be moved to data
        mutable_data = data.data.copy()
        unmarshaled_blob_names = []
        json_parser = parsers.JSONParser()
        for name, blob in data.files.items():
            if blob.content_type == 'application/json' and name not in data.data:
                parsed = json_parser.parse(blob)
                if isinstance(parsed, list):
                    # need to break it out into [0], [1] etc
                    for idx, item in enumerate(parsed):
                        mutable_data[name+f"[{str(idx)}]"] = item
                else:
                    mutable_data[name] = parsed
                unmarshaled_blob_names.append(name)
        for name in unmarshaled_blob_names:
            del data.files[name]
        data.data = mutable_data

        return data
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me.

```
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import SimpleUploadedFile
import requests
from typing import Dict

with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
    file = SimpleUploadedFile('Your-Name', f.read())

    data: Dict[str,str]
    files: Dict[str,SimpleUploadedFile] = {'model_field_name': file}

    requests.put(url, headers=headers, data=data, files=files)
    requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data, files=files)
```

`'model_field_name'` is the name of the `FileField` or `ImageField` in your Django model. You can pass other data as `name` or `location` as usual by using `data` parameter.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This work for me:

```
class FileUpload(APIView):
    parser_classes = [MultiPartParser]
    authentication_classes = [JWTAuthentication]

    def post(self, request, filename, format=None):
       file = request.data['file']
       data = json.loads(request.POST['form'])
       #.... just do.....
```

.
.
.

frontend part: example with fetch (vue frontend)

```
let data = await new FormData(); // creates a new FormData object
data.append("file", this.files); // add your file to form data
data.append('form',JSON.stringify(body)) //add your json

fetch(`https://endpoint/FileUpload/${body.nombre}`, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: data, 
  headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`}
              })
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was just writing another question on SO because none of the answers above were working for me.

I somehow found out, that for nested serializers, DRF accepts values in dotted notation. So if you have a Location serializer with x and y values, you can set the name of the field in your form to location.x and location.y and it will work.

If you want to send JSON, you can use this serializer, it will work.

```
from rest_framework import parsers
from django.http import QueryDict
import json

class MultipartJsonParser(parsers.MultiPartParser):

def parse(self, stream, media_type=None, parser_context=None):
    result = super().parse(
        stream,
        media_type=media_type,
        parser_context=parser_context
    )


    data = {}
   

    #For nested serializers, drf accepts values in dotted notaion (if sent as Multipart/Formdata). E.g if location is nested serializer.
    # It will accept location.x and location.y if data is to be entered in form fields.
    # the 2 nested for loops, ensures that the JSON data sent in form field is converted to the above format.
    #e.g if the key is asset_location. and it has x and y keys inside. It will be converted to asset_location.x, and asset_location.y


    for key, value in result.data.items():
        if type(value) != str:
            data[key] = value
            continue
        if '{' in value or "[" in value:
            try:
                data[key] = json.loads(value)
               
                if type(data[key]) == dict:
                    for inner_key,inner_value in data[key].items():
                        data[f'{key}.{inner_key}']=inner_value
            except ValueError:
                data[key] = value
        else:
            data[key] = value

    qdict = QueryDict('', mutable=True)
    qdict.update(data)
    print(qdict)
    return parsers.DataAndFiles(qdict, result.files)
```