# Store image in /media/ and save the URL in DB

Tags: python, django, post, django-views, django-rest-framework

I'm working in an API with Django Rest Framework and I need to store the full URL for an image in my db. I think in that way is easiest to send it via json.

I receive the image from POST request. I am using a RESTfull tool client to test, I get something like this in the view `post` method:

```
<InMemoryUploadedFile: profile_1.jpg (image/jpeg)>
```

In my model I have this:

```
photo_url = models.URLField(null=True)
```

My original idea was store it in a external server and store the url, but now I need to store the image in my own server but store only the url in my db. How can I achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever read [managing files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/files/) section in Django documentation?

Comment: @ozgur Yes I did, but it's about text files, when talk about images it's with a ImageField in a model or in a Form. This is an API I just receive a JSON in my backend.

Comment: DRF supports returning the url to the file with an `ImageField`, and there are plenty of [custom `ImageField` subclasses](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28036404/359284) that you can use for JSON. Is there any reason why you _have_ to use a `URLField` in your model?

Comment: Model was made when I take this project, and I don't want to change it.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this by doing as follow:

```
def get_encoded_image(encoded_image=None):

    """
    Save the received in request base64 encoded image and return the image path to serve.
    """

    _file = str(encoded_image)
    _file = base64.b64decode(_file)
    path = default_storage.save('{folder}/{file_name}.{extension}'.format(folder=settings.DEFAULT_PROFILE_IMAGES_FOLDER,
                                                                          file_name=time.time().__str__(),
                                                                          extension='jpg'),

                                ContentFile(_file))
    if settings.DEBUG:
        image_url = urljoin(settings.DEV_DOMAIN, '{media}{path}'.format(media=settings.MEDIA_URL,
                                                                        path=path))
    else:
        image_url = urljoin(settings.DOMAIN, '{media}{path}'.format(media=settings.MEDIA_URL,
                                                                    path=path))
    return image_url
```

I received the image encoded with base64 in a POST request. I used the [.time](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html) module to get a unique name, but Django adds a hash at the end of the file name if there's another with the same name.

Note variables like:

- `DEFAULT_PROFILE_IMAGES_FOLDER`: Name of the folder to store the images (inside `media` folder).
- `DEBUG`: Django's debug variable.
- `DEV_DOMAIN`: In my case, this is my `http://localhost:8000`
- `DOMAIN`: Server's IP or domain where application is running.