# DRF The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form - ImageField

Tags: json, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have the following model `User` serializer:

The `team` field is a `ForeignKey` in the `User` model and it's serialized for optimize their query in performance with the `setup_eager_loading` function

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    team = serializers.StringRelatedField()

    def setup_eager_loading(queryset):
      queryset = queryset.select_related('team',)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username','password','first_name','last_name',
        'photo','team','position','last_login',)
```

My `viewset` to `User` is the folowing:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework import filters

from .models import User
from .serializers import UserSerializer



# Viewsets define the behavior of the view
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = User.objects.all().order_by('-date_joined')
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    filter_fields = ('username','is_player', 'first_name','last_name','team','email',)
```

When I go to an user instance in my api serializers and I want update via `raw data media type: application/json`, I get the following message:

[image]

In my `User` model the image field is defined of this way:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
#... other attributes  
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars', blank=True)
```

How to can I update any field/attribute in my User serialized model via JSON raw data without appear this message about of encoding type in the `photo` field

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28036805/2773461) talk about of base64 encoded string in relation to DRF expected in the update request, but I try adding the `Base64ImageField` serializer and using it in my `UserSerializer` class but I get this:

[image]

with the exception:

```
Exception Value: Incorrect padding
```