# "The submitted data was not a file" error uploading images with Django REST Framework

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, antd

I have a Django Rest API for adding multiple images to a database. I am using React JS as my client side and to need to upload multiple images. I am using 
this component for uploading images in the client side.

https://ant.design/components/upload/

When calling the Django REST API, it shows the error "the submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form."

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28036404/django-rest-framework-upload-image-the-submitted-data-was-not-a-file)

Comment: I need to change this in the client side