# Failing to upload video from ReactJS to Django

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

Hey so I am busy with a ReactJS & Django project, I would love to upload videos on this app that I am doing, so I tried two different methods and all did not work I do not know where my implementation is wrong.

**Method1: Here I used the `fetch` to make a POST request to the URL `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/upload-lecture/`**

- With this method, I had an onChange event listener so to change the state of the video property then, right away put every captured content from form to the FormData the make POST request

**Code Below:**

```
    uploadVideo = (e) => {

        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.state);
        let form_data = new FormData();
        form_data.append('lecturer', this.state.lecturer);
        form_data.append('module', this.state.module);
        form_data.append('video', this.state.video);
        form_data.append('date', this.state.date);
        let url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/upload-lecture/';
        
        fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: form_data
      
        }).then(response => console.log(response)).catch(error => console.log(error))

      };
    }
```

**So after running method1 I checked the API logs and this is what I found**

**`[*] Error: {'video': [ErrorDetail(string='The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form.', code='invalid')]}`**

So I then attempted using another method, that is first using the JavaScript FileReader before I change the state of my video

**Code Below: This is the second way in which I tried to handle the video upload**

```
    handleVideo = (e) => {
        let files = e.target.files;
        let video = [];

        console.log(files);
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = r => {
            video.push(r.target.result);
            console.log("Done!!!!!!!!!");
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
        this.setState({
            video:video
        })
    }
```

then after the code below, I used the same code that I initially had to POST data but now first I used FileReader on the video.

**After all that when I tried to make a `POST` request I went to check the API logs and this is what I got:**

```
Request body exceeded settings.DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE.
Bad Request: /api/upload-lecture/
[17/Aug/2020 04:56:44] "POST /api/upload-lecture/ HTTP/1.1" 400 128016
```

Then from here, I reached a dead-end not knowing what am I really missing to perform this task

Comment: what is the file size of the video you are trying to upload?

Comment: Okay so that is something I managed to fix byt going to ```settings.py``` and change MAX UPLOAD STORAGE

but now I am getting the following error

Comment: ```{"video":["The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form.```

Comment: Now this error is the one that I got from Method1 only initially but now I get from both method1 and 2

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28036404/django-rest-framework-upload-image-the-submitted-data-was-not-a-file) might help