# failed to update a form data containing an image

Tags: python, reactjs, django-rest-framework, axios

i am a little bit new to django rest and react ,
well i'am trying to update my buying form and change the state but i keep getting a bad request  and getting in the response:

```
error:The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form
```

my request:

```
const accept=()=> {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
    var config = {
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': "Token " + token,
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                 }  
            }
const data = form
data.state="semi_approved"
const formdata = new FormData()
  Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
    console.log(key+':',form[key])
    formdata.append(key,form[key])
  })
console.log(formdata)
axios.put(`${getForm}${match.params.id}/`,formdata,config).then(res => {
  console.log(res.data)
})
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to upload an image which would be uploaded as a base64 encoded string instead of a raw file. Multi part form data expects a full file. I think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28036404/django-rest-framework-upload-image-the-submitted-data-was-not-a-file) should help you out!