# Save base64 image in django file field

Tags: python, django, image, filefield

I have following input

```
"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA7YAAAISCAIAAAB3YsSDAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAA5JxJREFUeNrsnQl4FEX6xqcJJEAS7ivhBkMAQTSJ4h0QEQ+I90rAc1cOL3QBXXV1AV1dVwmrsCqQ9VwJ6HoC7oon0T8iEkABwRC5IeE+kkAIkPT/nfmSmprunskk5CDw/p55hu7qOr76api8........"
```

I want to save this file in file field. What can I do?

**models.py**

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_report)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I'm trying to do this

```
def get_file(data):
    from django.core.files import File
    return File(data)
```

and save return file to model instance

```
somemodel.file = get_file(image_base64_data)
```

but it's gives a following error

```
AttributeError at /someurl/

'File' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Comment: posibel answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15115730/saving-a-decoded-temporary-image-to-django-imagefield

Comment: @Anna Vracheva I'm try this answer but not solve my problem.

Comment: The solution is the same as mentioned by @AnnaVracheva. Decode your base64, and create a ContentFile instance, and assign that to your model field. Can you explain what problem did you face in that?

Comment: i cant seem to decode the provided base64 string, are sure you have provided the right one ?

Comment: Please note your input is not a base64 image it is a HTTP Data-URI

that is the source of your problem, the answers below provide solutions by removing the data-uri definition from actual base64 data

Answer (score 85, accepted):

```
import base64

from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
format, imgstr = data.split(';base64,') 
ext = format.split('/')[-1] 

data = ContentFile(base64.b64decode(imgstr), name='temp.' + ext) # You can save this as file instance.
```

Use this code snippet to decode the base64 string.

Comment: after this, How can i save the data in image form field?

Comment: @squal you just need to pass the data to the file/image field on you model like `Image.objects.create(data)`, see my answer bellow

Comment: hi, its saves a blank image https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69358408/base64-saves-blank-image-django please can you help me

Answer (score 29):

```
import base64
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

image_data = requestData['user']['image']
format, imgstr = image_data.split(';base64,')
print("format", format)
ext = format.split('/')[-1]

data = ContentFile(base64.b64decode(imgstr))  
file_name = "'myphoto." + ext
user.image.save(file_name, data, save=True) # image is User's model field
```

Answer (score 16):

it's an old thread but this can be helpful:

```
import base64
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile


def base64_file(data, name=None):
    _format, _img_str = data.split(';base64,')
    _name, ext = _format.split('/')
    if not name:
        name = _name.split(":")[-1]
    return ContentFile(base64.b64decode(_img_str), name='{}.{}'.format(name, ext))
```

and you can use it like:

```
from my_app.models import ImageModel, FileModel

image = ImageModel.objects.create(base64_file(img_base64_str))

# or even base64 files, with custome name
file = FileModel.objects.create(base64_file(data=img_base64_str, name="custome_name"))
```

and also if you need base64 encoded files for test, here you go:

```
test_file_1 = "data:image/png;base64,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"
test_file_2 = "data:image/png;base64,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"
```

Comment: Am getting this `a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`, yet it's a byte

Comment: hi, it save a blank image https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69358408/base64-saves-blank-image-django

Answer (score 3):

This question looks like it should help: [Django - how to create a file and save it to a model's FileField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7514964/django-how-to-create-a-file-and-save-it-to-a-models-filefield)

You should be able to decode the base64 string and supply that as the `content` argument to [`FieldFile.save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.save):

Answer (score 1):

you can use [django-base64field](https://pypi.org/project/django-base64field/) package

```
from django_base64field.fields import Base64Field

class SomeModel(models.Model):
    file = Base64Field(max_length=900000, blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: This is nothing to do with images, this package is to generate a BASE64 string depending on your Model's PK.