# Treat a string as a file in python

Tags: python, string, io

In the interest of *not* rewriting an open source library,  I want to treat a string of text as a file in python 3.

Suppose I have the file contents as a string:

```
not_a_file = 'there is a lot of blah blah in this so-called file'
```

I want to treat this variable, i.e. the contents of a file, as a  [path-like object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-path-like-object) that way I can use it in python's `open()` [function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).

Here is a simple example which shows my dilemma:

```
not_a_file = 'there is a lot of blah blah in this so-called file'
file_ptr = open(not_a_file, 'r')
```

Clearly the example doesn't work because `not_a_file` is not a path-like object.  I don't want to write a file nor create any temporary directories for portability purposes.

With that said, I need is to solve this mystery:

```
not_a_file = 'there is a lot of blah blah in this so-called file'
... Something goes here ... 
file_ptr = open(also_not_a_file, 'r')
```

### What I've Tried So Far

1. I've looked into StringIO and tried using that as a path-like object and no dice:

   `import StringIO
   output = StringIO.StringIO()
   output.write('First line.\n')
   file_ptr = open(output,'r')`

   Well this doesn't work because StringIO isn't a path-like object.
2. I've tried tempfile in a similar fashion with no success.

   `import tempfile
   tp = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
   tp.write(b'there is a lot of blah blah in this so-called file')
   open(tp,'r')`
3. Finally I tried mmap to see if I can write the string into memory and then open the memory pointer with `open` with no success.

Any help is appreciated! :-)

### Edit 1: What I'm thinking of to possibly solve problem

So `pathlib.PurePath` can work with `open()` if [PurePath](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pure-paths) is initialized to a file.  Perhaps I can create an instance of a class that inherits PurePath and when read by `open()`, it reads my string.  Let me give an example:

```
from pathlib import PurePath

not_a_file = 'there is a lot of blah blah in this so-called file'
class Magic(PurePath):
    def __init__(self, string_input):
        self.file_content = string_input
        PurePath.__init__(self, 'Something magical goes here')
    #some more magic happens in this class

also_not_a_file = Magic(not_a_file)
fp = open(also_not_a_file,'r')
print(fp.readlines()) # 'there is a lot of blah blah in this so-called file'
```

Comment: Why do you want to use the open command?  output.write("line 1\n"); output.seek(0); file_ptr=output

Comment: @clockwatcher so in a different library that I'm going to use, there is this `open` command expecting the usual file input.  For my purposes and portability I need to somehow pass the string into the `open` somehow.

Comment: Is there a way to use pathlib.PurePath with a string to create an object that will read the string?   `open(pathlib.PurePath('path/to/filename.ext'),'r')` is valid python.  Can I incorporate `PurePath` and my string into a class which when passed into `open()` reads my string?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I wrap a string in a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141449/how-do-i-wrap-a-string-in-a-file-in-python)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create a temporary file and pass its name to open:

On Unix:

```
tp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
tp.write(b'there is a lot of blah blah blah in this so-called file')
tp.flush()
open(tp.name, 'r')
```

On Windows, you need to close the temporary file before it can be opened:

```
tp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
tp.write(b'there is a lot of blah blah blah in this so-called file')
tp.close()
open(tp.name, 'r')
```

You then become responsible for deleting the file once you're done using it.

Comment: Did you pass `tp.name` and not `tp` to open?

Comment: The unix example isn't working for me.  Is NamedTemporaryFile() a path-like object?

I get:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _TemporaryFileWrapper

Comment: I'm still not able to read the contents of the object properly.  `open(tp.name, 'r').readlines()` just gives me `''`

Answer (score 29):

StringIO returns an `StringIO` object, it's almost equivalent to the file object returned by the `open` statement. So basically, you can use the StringIO in place of the `open` statement.

```
# from StringIO import StringIO  # for Python 2, old
from io import StringIO
with StringIO('there is a lot of blah blah in this so-called file') as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Output:

```
there is a lot of blah blah in this so-called file
```

Comment: This won't suffice.  I would need a path like object `also_not_a_string` to be a valid input into `open()`.  This object, when read via `open()` should have the 'there is a lot of blah blah in this so-called file' string.

Comment: So you're basically wanting to create a real existing file onto storage? Since `open()` must take an openable file name/path as an argument. You *can* use tempfile, but that's just like creating a file, use it, and delete it later. Is that what you want instead?

Comment: See my revised edit of #2.  That is an example of tempfile which does not work.  Again, I need a path-like object when read via `open()`, yields the string 'there is a lot of blah blah in this so-called file'

Comment: Sometimes (rarely) this simply is not possible.  TensorFlow is one such rare problem.  You must specify a filename and cannot send in a file object/pointer.

Answer (score 3):

With what I can tell from your comments and recent edits, you want a file that can be opened using the `open` statement. (I'll leave my other answer be since it's the more correct approach to this type of question)

You *can* use `tempfile` to solve your problem, it basically is doing this: create your file, do stuff to your file, then delete your file upon closure.

```
import os
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

f = NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w+', delete=False)
f.write("there is a lot of blah blah in this so-called file")
f.close()
with open(f.name, "r") as new_f:
    print(new_f.read())

os.unlink(f.name) # delete the file after
```

Answer (score 0):

the other answers didn't work for me, but I managed to figure it out.

When using Python 3, you'll want to use [io package](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html).

```py
    import io
    with io.StringIO("some initial text data") as f:
        # now you can do things with f as if it was an opened file.
        function_that_requires_a_Fileobject_as_argument(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite what `open` means for a particular function - similarly to what `unittest.mock.patch` does. However to do so, you have to keep track of the module where your target function is located. To make sure that later on `open` is restored, you can take advantage of decorators or context managers:

```py
class FileToStringIOPatch:
    def __init__(self, module, new_reader=io.StringIO, **kwargs):
        self.new_reader = new_reader
        self.globals_dict = vars(module)
        self.old_open = self.globals_dict.get('open', open)
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def __enter__(self):  # initialize context manager - overwrite `open`
        def new_open(file, mode='r', buffering=None, encoding=None, errors=None, newline=None, closefd=True):
            return self.new_reader(file, **self.kwargs)
        self.globals_dict['open'] = new_open

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb): # close ctx manager - restore `open`
        self.globals_dict['open'] = self.old_open
```

Example usage when "mocked" function declaration is in the same module as where it's called:

```py
def read(path):
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        print(f.read())

# ...
import sys
module_reference = sys.modules[__name__]

string = "siala_baba_mak"
with FileToStringIOPatch(module_reference)
    read(string)  # prints siala_baba_mak
read('path/to/file.txt')  # outside of context manager it still works as usual
```

Example usage when "mocked" function declaration is in another module

```py
def read(path):
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        print(f.read())

# ...

from xyz import read
import xyz
module_reference = xyz

string = "siala_baba_mak"
with FileToStringIOPatch(module_reference)
    read(string)  # prints siala_baba_mak
read('path/to/file.txt')  # outside of context manager it still works as usual
```

You can even provide custom readers to add additional functionalities e.g. reading from AWS S3 bucket.

```py
from s3path import S3Path
path = S3Path("s3://path/to/file.txt")
with FileToStringIOPatch(module_reference, new_reader=path.open):
    read_(path)
```