# Open downloaded image in python opencv from variable instead of file

Tags: python, opencv

I want to load to opencv an image that I've downloaded. I would like to avoid saving it to a file. I can perfectly download the image:

```
page_html = requests.get("http://my_web_page.com")

image_src = parse.search('<img id="my_image" src="{}"', page_html.content.decode('utf-8'))[0]
if image_src:
    image = requests.get("http://my_web_age.com" + image_src).content
```

And I can save it to a file and check it with my file explorer:

```
with open('main_image.png', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(image.content)
```

But if I try to directly load the image from the content of the variable, it doesn't work:

```
cv2_image = cv2.imread(image.content, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```

I get:

```
SystemError: <built-in function imread> returned NULL without setting an error
```

Reading from the file works nevertheless, but is it possible to skip this step? The data is already in the variable, so it should be possible.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141449/how-do-i-wrap-a-string-in-a-file-in-python This sounds like it may do what you need. Create a file object from a string.

Comment: @JammyDodger but it is not a string, is a bytes object. Do you think is the right direction? And it seems to be only for python2?

Comment: i see in the docs that `cv2.imread` takes filepath as first parameter

Answer (score 2):

You can use numpy's [frombuffer](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html) to convert the data to integers. [imdecode](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.5/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga26a67788faa58ade337f8d28ba0eb19e) then turns it into an image array you use with opencv.

Working example:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import requests

# perform request
response =  requests.get('https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_images/messiup.jpg').content
# convert to array of ints
nparr = np.frombuffer(response, np.uint8)
# convert to image array
img = cv2.imdecode(nparr,cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

# showimage
cv2.imshow("Res", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```